# create new instance from existing instance and new class instance change existing class params

Tags: java, instance, clone

Let's say we have a setup like this

```
public class foo {
    int number = 0;
    public void setNumber(int number) {
         this.number = number;
    }
}

public class bar extends foo {
    /* Some other utilities added to the foo class */
    public bar() {
         super();
    }
}
```

And we have this task running

```
Scheduler.schedule(1000/* Every second */, () -> {
    fooManager.forEach(f -> System.out.println(f.getNumber()));
})
```

Now if we do this:

```
Foo fo = new foo();
fooManager.store(fo);
Bar ba = new bar();
```

How can I make `ba` access `fo` `setNumber()` method on `ba.setNumber()` without storing `fo` in `ba` and doing `ba.getFoInstance().setNumber()` and do `ba.setNumber()` instead

Explanation v2: I want `ba.setNumber()` to call `fa.setNumber()`

Looking for something like this: `Bar ba = fo` but you can't do that since it throws `ClassCastException`.

Comment: `super()` will call the Constructor of foo class. You can do `super.setNumer(...)` to invoke the `setNumber()` method.

Comment: @user2004685 The "fooManager" has the `foo` stored so if you edit bar it won't edit the foo element in the `foo` list Made an edit - Also it would have no effect because `ba.setNumber()` calls the super method by default

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. You want `ba.setNumber()` to actually perform `fo.setNumber()`, even though `ba` and `fo` are different objects, and without storing a reference to `fo` inside of `ba`?

Comment: When I create `ba` I want to use `fa` as the extended instance @AdiLevin
so that `ba.setNumber()` would call `fa.setNumber()`

Comment: Oh. I see. Makes sense.

Comment: You can use java.reflection.Proxy or CGLIB library. But as already said, don't make you architecture to much complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that what you're trying to achieve is a [proxy object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern).
Why shouldn't you want to keep a reference to `Foo` inside instances of `Bar` class? It could make sense something like this:

```
public class Bar extends Foo {

    private Foo fa;

    public bar(Foo fa) {
        super();
        this.fa = fa;
    }

    @Override
    public void setNumber (int number) {
        fa.setNumber(number);
    }

    @Override
    public int getNumber () {
        return fa.getNumber();
    }
}
```

You should also avoid `Bar` extending `Foo`, they should simply both implement the same interface that is sharing the common methods.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, `ba` and `fo` need to keep a reference to the same `number` variable. So either `ba` keeps a reference to `fo`, or both `fo` and `ba` keep a reference to a common object that contains the `number`.

Comment: I ended up storing `Foo` in `Bar` for now, I guess we need to wait it's possible with cloning or Reflections

Comment: I recommend that you keep it simple. Try to use the simplest Java features, so that your code isn't based too much on reflection magic. If you find that regular object oriented constructs are not suitable, take a second look at your object oriented design. Maybe your class structure can be improved.